# How to upgrade amber framework?

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

my crystal version is 0.26.1
my amber version is 0.7.2

I would like to upgrade my amber framework installation to the latest stable version (currently 0.9.0). What is the best way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Upon further inspection, this looks like something the `shard.yml` would be good for:

```
crystal: 0.26.1
dependencies:
    amber:
        github: Amber-Crystal/amber 
        branch: BRANCH_HERE
```

`BRANCH_HERE`: being something like `master`, or `stable`

Also see :

- [SPEC.md on master](https://github.com/crystal-lang/shards/blob/master/SPEC.md)

  - [from commit](https://github.com/crystal-lang/shards/blob/3b724ef5dbf826e23a89abea3717e7c1f95caf5a/SPEC.md)

Where you can also use the `version` key.

*However, without any shard/package management.*

See where they are currently located:

```
which amber
which crystal
```

Upgrading `amber`:

```
export VERSION=0.10.0
wget "https://github.com/amberframework/amber/archive/v$VERSION.tar.gz"
tar xvfz $VERSION.tar.gz
cd amber-$VERSION
make
make install # perhaps sudo
```

It will build a dist and overwrite `/usr/local/bin/amber` with the new one.

Upgrading `crystal`:

```
export CRYSTAL_VERS=0.26.1
wget "https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/archive/$CRYSTAL_VERS.tar.gz"
tar xvfz $CRYSTAL_VERS.tar.gz
cd crystal-$CRYSTAL_VERS
make
ln -s [full path to bin/crystal] /usr/local/bin/crystal
```

There are pre-compiled versions targeting specific systems as well, which can be found here: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/releases

With those you'll be able to skip the build/compile step.

**As far as code migration, I'm not sure what sort of migration tools are currently available, but you'll want to check the changelogs for any breaking changes**